# How to pass JSON MongoDB Query object from Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, mongodb, mongodb-query

- I am passing **JSON data** from my **iOS** app to my backend **MongoDB** server
- The **JSON data** consists of two parent fields **userData** & **queryData**
- I pass this via **POST** request as `req.body` and retrieve the data in the server as `req.body.userData` and `req.body.queryData`
- I use swift **CODABLE** to encode this object to jSON and send it to the server

Everything works fine. I am able to extract `req.body.userData` and play around with it. What I do not understand is, how do I extract a **mongo query** from `req.body.queryData` and pass it to a mongo `find()` method?

**For example** - How do I pass

```
{
  "fieldOne": {"$in": [1, 2, 3]}, 
  "fieldTwo": {"$ne": "Admin"}
}
```

The above is **MongoDB syntax** to filter data. How can I make my **codable** struct send this format? Right now I am simply declaring the struct as **string**. I am new to working with server side and JSONS.

Here is my struct - like I said, req.body.userData works fine

```
struct QueryData: Codable {
        var fieldOne: String
        var fieldTwo: String
    }
```

Comment: your example is not really a JSON string, it should be

{
  "fieldOne": {"$in": [1, 2, 3]},
  "fieldTwo": {"$ne": "Admin"}
}

Comment: @ChaolongLiao Yes that's right. I posted the NodeJS format. In NodeJS fieldValues are written without quotes. Will edit it now

Comment: Maybe you may find some solutions with this lib : https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-swift-driver. Hopefully, you are not performing any mongodb query directly from an iOS app

Comment: @Zyigh this driver seems to directly access the mongo database. And yes I am not performing any queries or hitting the database directly from the ios app. The server handles it. Was just trying to figure out how I can send filter options to the server

Comment: @Archid I used that lib in a Swift backend project and it was ok enough for what we were trying to do. I can't tell you the impact on the size of your app but it might be a useful workaround as the type `BSONDocument` implements `Codable` and can be easily encoded. I didn't write that as an answer as it can be a bit "barbarian" to add the whole library in order to use only one data structure, but it's really convenient when you have to deall with MongoDB json-like format

Comment: @Zyigh Yes will look into it. Thanks for the input

Answer (score 1):

```swift
import Foundation

let mongo = """
{
  "fieldOne": {"$in": [1, 2, 3]},
  "fieldTwo": {"$ne": "Admin"}
}
"""

struct FieldOne: Codable {
    var `in`: [Int]
    
    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case `in` = "$in"
    }
}

struct FieldTwo: Codable {
    var ne: String
    
    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case ne = "$ne"
    }
}

struct QueryData: Codable {
    var fieldOne: FieldOne
    var fieldTwo: FieldTwo
}

let jsonObject = try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: mongo.data(using: .utf8)!, options: [])
print(jsonObject)
```

I try to parse you example in swift playground

Comment: Why you are not using the `Codable` models that you created and instead use `JSONSerialization`?